# clear HTML input after enter and prevent new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit the value of a textbox when the user presses enter, and finally clear the input. I tried this code:

```
input.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val('');
        ...
    }
```

The input field's text clears as it's supposed to, but after clearing, the newline is still entered in the input. This means that the user has to remove this newline after sending a message every time. Is there a way to prevent this newline from appearing, aside from hack-ish methods like setting an interval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return false when enter is pressed:

```
input.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course this means that your end-user won't be able to actually create a new line. In this case I usually have a boolean variable that changes when the shift key is pressed/released. So  if shift is down, don't submit, make a new line.

Comment: No problem, take note of my new line suggestion. It really annoys me if I come across an application that prevents me from making a new line in a text-box. Remember to accept if you got everything you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that. I couldn't accept the answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're submitting with AJAX you can clear the input after collecting the data for the AJAX payload.

If you're doing a regular page changing submit, you could add an `onbeforeunload` callback that clears the input.

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` in the `keydown` event, this prevents the event from bubbling down so it never actually does anything to the textbox.

```
input.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).val('');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```